# Convert unixtime to TIMESTAMP in HiveSQL

Tags: sql, hive

How do I convert unix epoch time to TIMESTAMP in HiveSQL?

The built-in date function `from_unixtime` is converting it to string and not TIMESTAMP. `to_utc_timestamp` only seem to convert timestamps from a timezone to UTC.

Is there any function that converts directly from a unix timestamp as BIGINT to TIMESTAMP?

**Example**

```
SELECT to_timestamp(1427976376) FROM mytable; --> 2015-04-02 14:06:16
```

**EDIT:**

The best option I can find, although not great, is

```
SELECT cast(from_unixtime(1427976376) as TIMESTAMP) FROM mytable;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try following:

```
SELECT from_unixtime(unix_timestamp) as new_timestamp from mytable...
```

It converting unix timestamp into `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format, then you can use following function to get the year, month, and day:

```
SELECT year(new_timestamp) as year, month(new_timestamp) as month, day(new_timestamp) as day ...
```

Comment: But that doesn't give me a result of the type TIMESTAMP at all. I need it as TIMESTAMP not separated into year and month etc.

Comment: So how about `CONCAT()` function? http://www.thelandbeyondspreadsheets.com/how-to-join-strings-in-sql-for-hive/

Comment: No, that would give me a STRING and would be a very tedious way of getting the same as from_unixtime gives me in the first place.